# How can I make this Tkinter app run faster

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've written a simple Conway's Game of Life in Python Tk, but it is so utterly slow!
On my PC it ran somewhat fine, but on my school computers it couldn't reach 10 refreshes a second. I suspect the drawing part lags a lot, how can I fix that?

```python
def drawCells(self):
    self.board.delete(tk.ALL)
    for i in range(self.gridsize):
        for j in range(self.gridsize):
            if self.cnow[j][i] == 1: # cells now list
                rect = self.board.create_rectangle(
                    i * self.grid,
                    j * self.grid,
                    (i + 1) * self.grid,
                    (j + 1) * self.grid,
                    fill="#000000")
```

I don't know if pasting the entire class is necessary, but if needed I'll append the rest of the code.

Comment: what sizes are you simulating, with what? lists or numpy? Optimization is normally a thing for http://codereview.stackexchange.com. and for anything that is not using a crystal ball, enhanced clairvoyance and the lookFutureAI.dll this piece of code is not really helpfull. Read up on codereview posting rules and post it according to theire rules there. moving this questions probably not needed as it is not complete enough.

Comment: Maybe you can try changing the color of the squares instead of deleting and recreating  them.

Comment: Above code isn't an _app_ by itself. Please provide a [mcve] specifically for this part of the GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating items on the canvas is slow, and the more you create the slower it gets (even if you delete them each time). Instead, create the rectangles once and then simply reconfigure them on each generation.

The `create_rectangle` method returns an integer id. Save these ids, then use the `itemconfigure` method to change the color.

Answer (score 0):

All I can suggest is rewriting the code without embedding two for-loops (that'll improve your time complexity some), but I'm not sure if that'll fix your problem entirely as I do not know what else is going on in your class.

Best of luck!